# Is it possible to cut holes in polygons with folium?

Tags: python-3.x, folium

I am using Folium in Python 3 to draw shapes on a map. 
I would like to draw a polygon, and then cut a "hole" in it, using another polygon.

The following code draws 2 polygons one over the other. Is there a way to combine them in order to only draw the part of the first polygon not covered by the second ?

```
import folium

cornerA=[0, 0]
cornerB=[0, 1]
cornerC=[1, 1]
cornerD=[1, 0]

m = folium.Map(location=cornerA, tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=8)

border_1=[cornerA,cornerB,cornerC,cornerD]
folium.vector_layers.Polygon(border_1,color='red',fill_color='red',fill_opacity=0.5,weight=4).add_to(m)

cornerE=[0.25,0.25]
cornerF=[0.25,0.5]
cornerG=[0.5,0.5]
cornerH=[0.5,0.25]
border_2=[cornerE,cornerF,cornerG,cornerH]
folium.vector_layers.Polygon(border_2,color='blue',fill_color='blue',fill_opacity=0.5,weight=4).add_to(m)
m.save('My_map.html')
```

A workaround is to draw the wanted polygon combining explicitely every corner, but it is not practical.

```
m = folium.Map(location=cornerA, tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=8)
border_3=[cornerA,cornerE,cornerF,cornerG,cornerH,cornerE,cornerA,cornerB,cornerC,cornerD]
folium.vector_layers.Polygon(border_3,color='blue',fill_color='blue',fill_opacity=0.5,weight=4).add_to(m)
m.save('My_map.html')
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks !

Comment: As far as I know this is not something folium does. Please look into the Shapely library, which should be able to help with this. Alternatively, I also did polygon manipulation with Matplotlib once but not sure if that's applicable here.

Comment: Indeed, the Shapely function "difference" does that very well, and the Geopandas function "overlay", option "how='difference'", does that too. Thanks